# How to refactor a Java file which has more than 50000 lines?

Tags: java, spring, class, refactoring

I have a java class which has more than 50,000 lines of codes. I want to refactor it and make multiple small classes.

I have tried making child classes but there are challenges (correct me if I am wrong)

a. we cannot call child method with parent object!

b. Furthermore, we can not call a method which is in child from parent.

```
public class Parent {

    public void a(){
        System.out.println("Parent :: a");
        b();          //point b
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{

    public void b(){
        System.out.println("Child :: m");
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Parent();
        p.b();         //point a       

        Child c = new Child();
        c.a();
    }
}
```

Edit: The parent class is a @ManagedBean class ( I am using JSF and Spring ).

Comment: Is the above code alread the result of a refactoring you have in mind? How would the original code look like (not the 50K lines, of course)?

Comment: @LutzHorn it's that rare case when we don't want to see OP's code ;)

Comment: @LutzHorn the parent class is the class having 50k lines. The code which I showed is after we divide it into child classes and the challenges that arises with it.
If it helps, we can just consider parent class with many methods and suggest a solution.

Answer (score 4):

**Point B**

You can, it's called [the template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). A parent may define

> the skeleton of an operation in terms of a number of high-level steps. These steps are themselves implemented by additional helper methods in the same class as the template method.
>
> The helper methods *may be either abstract methods, for which case subclasses are required to provide concrete implementations*, or hook methods, which have empty bodies in the superclass.

The highlighted part is what I would prefer.

```
public abstract class Parent {
    public void a(){
        System.out.println("Parent :: a");
        b();
    }
    public abstract void b();  // shouldn't necessarily be public
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    public void b(){
        System.out.println("Child :: m");
    }
}
```

**Point A**

You can't, it's not a part of parent's interface. Either add the method to the parent or rethink why it's called on a parent reference.

Comment: hi, thank you for an answer, I have updated my original question.
We can not make objects of the abstract class as my Parent class is a @ManagedBean class.

Answer (score 0):

A and B can be achieved by the use  of polymorphism

```
public class Parent {

    public void a(){
        System.out.println("Parent :: a");
        b();          //point b
    }

    public void b() {
         System.out.println("not in use");
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{

    @Override
    public void b(){
        System.out.println("Child :: m");
    }
}


    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Child();
        p.b();         
        p.a();        

    }
}
```

results:

```
Child:: m
Parent:: a
Child:: m
```

Comment: hi, thank you for an answer, I have updated my original question. We can not make objects of the abstract class as my Parent class is a @ManagedBean class.

Comment: I edited the answer it's a bit crooked but still gives solution